# Embedded Tomcat and Jersey is not working when i deploy into linux

Tags: java, tomcat

1. Embedded tomcat and Jersey is working fine in windows but when I
   deployed jar into my linux machine it's not working properly I am
   getting error like this:

   Using below code:

   ```
   public void start() throws ServletException , LifecycleException,
   MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

       //Define a folder to hold web application contents.         String
   webappDirLocation = "WebContent/";      Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
               //Define port number for the web application        String webPort = System.getenv("PORT");         if(webPort == null || webPort.isEmpty()){
           webPort = "8099";       }
               //Bind the port to Tomcat server        tomcat.setPort(Integer.valueOf(webPort));
               //Define a web application context.         Context context = tomcat.addWebapp("/tomcatembedded", new
   File(webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());
       String path = new File(webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath();

       System.out.println("path: "  + path); //        //Define and bind
   web.xml file location.          File configFile = new
   File(webappDirLocation + "WEB-INF/web.xml");
       context.setConfigFile(configFile.toURI().toURL());

       tomcat.start();

   }
   ```

   the above code working perfectly in my windows machine only problem
   with my linux machine.

> org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat getWebappConfigFileFromJar
>       WARNING: Unable to determine web application context.xml
>
> java.io.FileNotFoundException:/WebContent (No such file or
>       directory)    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)    at
>       java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:219)    at
>       java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:149)    at
>       java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:166)    at
>       java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:130)    at
>       org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.getWebappConfigFileFromJar(Tomcat.java:1137)
>         at
>       org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.getWebappConfigFile(Tomcat.java:1117)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.addWebapp(Tomcat.java:540)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.addWebapp(Tomcat.java:515)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.addWebapp(Tomcat.java:197)
>
> Sep 27, 2016 1:39:55 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
>       INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8099"] Sep 27, 2016
>       1:39:55 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool
>       getSharedSelector INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet
>       write/read Sep 27, 2016 1:39:55 AM
>       org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal INFO:
>       Starting service Tomcat Sep 27, 2016 1:39:55 AM
>       org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal INFO: Starting
>       Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.28 Sep 27, 2016 1:39:55 AM
>       org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processContextConfig
>       SEVERE: Missing context.xml

Please let me know what I missed in my code.

Comment: Please format your code; this is pretty much unreadable.

Comment: From the error message it looks like that `WebContent` directory is missing. Do you have that? Does it end up in the jar or war file?

Comment: Hi Robert Maven installed jar has my Webcontent/WEB-INF/web.xml folder but in linux when I ran jar it looks like Webcontent folder is missing

Comment: have you tried spring boot? It has embeded Tomcat also and much simpler to build

Comment: No I haven't try yet.

Comment: Do you have Webcontent or WebContent? Linux has case-sensitive file systems.

Comment: Added as WebContent